# Log file in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a log file where a change to a cell will be recorded with a date stamp.
The log file needs to record from few spreadsheets.
I've managed to get a code that records the change and I have pasted it to every spreadsheet.
Now the issue is that the recorded data from different spreadsheets is in one column and I'm not able to say from which spreadsheet it came from.
How to adjust the following code to move the recorded data from column ABC to EFG ?
Additionally, how to add a record of a specific cell lets say D4?
I'm completely new in this stuff so go easy on me please.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strAddress As String
Dim val
Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim Rw As Long

If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:M1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   'change range to suit
dtmTime = Now()
val = Target.Value
strAddress = Target.Address

Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets("Log Sheet")
    .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress
    .Cells(Rw, 2) = val
    .Cells(Rw, 3) = dtmTime
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code, **as it is**, in all the involved sheets. But **you must correctly define the `arrSheets` array in terms of sheets name and column letter where the record should start from**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim arrSheets As Variant, El As Variant, colLetter As String
 Dim strAddress As String, val, dtmTime As Date, Rw As Long

 If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:M1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 arrSheets = Split("Sheet1|A,Sheet2|E,Sheet40|I", ",") 'Fill here the involved sheets name and first col letter
 For Each El In arrSheets
    If Split(El, "|")(0) = Target.Parent.Name Then
        colLetter = Split(El, "|")(1): Exit For 'define the area where the log to be done
    End If
 Next
   'change range to suit
 dtmTime = Now()
 val = Target.value
 strAddress = Target.Address

 Rw = sheets("Log Sheet").Range(colLetter & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 With sheets("Log Sheet")
    .cells(Rw, colLetter).value = strAddress
    .cells(Rw, colLetter).Offset(, 1).value = val
    .cells(Rw, colLetter).Offset(, 2).value = dtmTime
 End With
End Sub
```

In case of frequent pages to be logged changes, a better solution would be to declare `Public Const arrStr As String = "Sheet1|A,Sheet2|E,Sheet40|I"` in the top side (declarations area) of a standard module.

Then, the event will create the array in the next way:

```
arrSheets = Split(arrStr, ",")
```

In this way, **if some more sheets will be involved**, any code update will be done only in one place, in the `Public` constant...

Comment: @Radek Szczerbinski: Did you find time to also test the above code? It can deal with as many sheets you need to process/log...

Comment: Radek, this is worth doing. My answer has answered your questions literally as put, whereas @FaneDuru has taken it a step further and made your mousetrap a little better and a little more future proof. I too suggest you try it as well.

Comment: Tried that one as well works perfect, Thanks FaneDuru great stuff

Comment: One more question, How to add the newest entry at the top of the list instead of the end of it?

Comment: @Radek Szczerbinski: Glad I could help! But doesn't it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

## Changing log columns from ABC to EFG

To change ABC to EFG, make change indicated bellow in comments

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strAddress As String
Dim val
Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim Rw As Long

If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:M1000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   'change range to suit
dtmTime = Now()
val = Target.Value
strAddress = Target.Address

Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets("Log Sheet")
    .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress --//Change 1 to 5 for E
    .Cells(Rw, 2) = val        --//Change 2 to 6 for F
    .Cells(Rw, 3) = dtmTime    --//Change 3 to 7 for G
End With
End Sub
```

Note: the above code is just copied from your question, except for the comments on those three rows.

## Adding name of worksheet that was changed

To add worksheet source (e.g. column H), you could insert the following line immediately before `End With`:

```
    .Cells(Rw, 4) = ActiveSheet.Name    --//Change 4 to 8 for H
```

## Recording a specific cell changed

To record ONLY if D4 changed, change your `Range("A1:M1000)"` to `Range("D4)"`

Comment: Thanks ed2,  adding of the worksheet name works, but when I'm changing 4 to 8 to move to column H it moves but only one record is created. Every time a new record has been done it overwrites the old one instead of placing it under it. any solution for that?

Comment: Yep. See this line `Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`? Change it to `Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` and let me know what happens